# Installing 32 bit glibc on 64 bit RHEL

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to install glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686 on 64 bit RHEL.  I understand it has a dependency on the NSSRAWHASH package (I'm using the nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-3.el6.i686.rpm package), so I run the following command to install both packages at the same time and resolve the circular dependency between the two.

```
rpm -ivh glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-3.el6.i686.rpm
```

However, I am still getting the following dependency error ...

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libfreebl3.so is needed by glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
    libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) is needed by glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686
```

I don't see why it is still having dependency issues.  Is there some other package I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

1. Try installing `nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-3.el6.i686.rpm` first.
2. Then, locate `libfreebl3.so` in your system.
3. Make sure that `libfreebl3.so`'s path (eg. `/usr/local/lib`) be in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
4. Try installing `glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686` again.

Comment: When I attempt to install nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-3.el6.i686.rpm alone, I still get the same exact error for some reason.

Comment: That's weird. Try to uninstall `glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686`.

Comment: Rather, uninstallation of the packages returns an error saying they're not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
rpm -ivh --force nss-softokn-freebl-3.12.9-3.el6.i686.rpm glibc-2.12-1.25.el6.i686.rpm
```